# Error : "failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition" when building a Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, debian-jessie

I get this error

## **failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition**

when I was trying to build this Docker image

**

````
FROM debian:jessie-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install iptables apt-utils iproute2 net-tools systemd telnet nano iputils-ping tcpdump inetutils-traceroute quagga isc-dhcp-server
RUN apt-get -f install
COPY  ./quagga /etc/quagga
COPY  ./dhcp/dhcpd.conf /etc/dhcp
COPY box_ext.sh /home/
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/home/box_ext.sh"]
RUN mkdir /etc/scripts
ENV PATH "/etc/scripts:$PATH"
ENTRYPOINT /etc/init.d/quagga start && /bin/bash
```**
````

Comment: Is that the entire error?  What command(s) are you running that produce it?  Do you know which line in the Dockerfile produces this problem?  The `apt-get install` line includes several packages I can't imagine a typical application using (`systemd`, `telnet`, `nano`); can you reduce the Dockerfile to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on MacOS Ventura using docker desktop version **4.9.1** when building a docker image from a Dockerfile. Error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.7-alpine": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http.docker.internal on <IP>: read udp <IP>:63475-><IP>:53: read: connection refused
make: *** [build-image] Error 1
```

Initially, I thought it was a connection issue as I was behind a proxy, But It worked just by restarting my Docker Desktop app (Click on the docker icon on the top-right bar > Press Restart).